# Javascript: preserve style when trying to block or hide a table's row(s)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table and I'm building a function to filter and view certain rows of the table, based on keyboard input from the filter bar.

I've tested the logic of my function to match the contents of the row ton user input and it works. i.e. If the user enters a substring of any word in a cell within the row (or not), I can successfully access the row to display (or hide) by getting the ID of it.

However, I'm having a little glitch with the style of the table being altered when I try to display or hide the rows.

Consider the HTML below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
<table id="current-books" class="u-full-width">
  <thead id="header">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>ISBN</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="book-list">
    <!-- Dynamically add books here -->
    <tr id="Book One Author One N/A">
      <td>Book One</td>
      <td>Author One</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="delete">X</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If I did something like this in JS in my function to show the row if the user input matched, the entire table gets "squished" which is not what I'd like:

```
match = "Book One Author One N/A";
document.getElementById('header').className = 'u-full-width';
document.getElementById(match).className = 'u-full-width';
/* The code below squishes the table's width from the width of page - no bueno */
document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(match).style.display = 'block';
```

Note that I'm using the Skeleton CSS framework for my styles. According to the documentation, "The class .u-full-width is just a utility class shorthand for width: 100%". I tried to preserve/reset the width by adding the classname as well, but that didn't work.

**How can I reset the width of the table?**

[Here's a JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qdcbro58/).

I'm working in POJS, so I'm not looking for solutions using JQuery etc,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of your jsfiddle link, it should by using the property `table-header-group`

```js
document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'table-header-group';
```

If you use 'block', the element `thead` will act like block element (like <p>). If you want the element behave like a <thead> element, you have to use `table-header-group` display property.

source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: That helps preserve the header, but the rows still mutate if I block them. I also realized the fiddle link I posted is not quite the same as the snippets in my post, so I've edited the link above.

Comment: For the rows it should use `table-row` property, not `block`. Second line of your jsfiddle code is setting `display = block` to a `tr` element that's why is breaks.